# como paso los elementos de una lista de una funcion a otra?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, funciones

quisiera saber como pasar la lista de la funcion "repite_pregunta" a la funcion "main". Trato con "return nombre" pero no la pasa. En que fallo?

```
def main():

    print('escribe algunos nombres y luego presiona enter:')        

    a = []

    repite_pregunta(a)

    print('los nombres que escribiste son:')

    print (a)


def repite_pregunta (nombre):

  nombre = []
  re_ingresar = True

  while re_ingresar:
    nombre.append(input())

    if name[-1] == '' :

      re_ingresar = False

  return nombre 


main()
```

ejemplo de output que quisiera:

```
escribe algunos nombres y luego presiona enter:
juan
pepe
rafael

los nombres que escribiste son:
['juan','pepe','rafael']
```

el ouput con el codigo actual:

```
escribe algunos nombres y luego presiona enter:
juan
pepe
rafael

los nombres que escribiste son:
[]
```

Comment: return false; cambialo por: re_ingresar = False y eso seria todo!

Comment: gracias, me ayudaste. Sin embargo la lista sale vacia [] solo me faltaria eso.

Comment: pon nombre =[] fuera de las funciones hasta antes del print('escribe algunos nombres y luego presiona enter:')

Answer (score 0):

En la función `repite_pregunta()` vacías la lista `nombre` cuando haces `nombre=[]`. Por otro lado el `return nombre` que haces al final sería supérfluo ya que la función está cambiando de todas formas la lista recibida a través del parámetro, por lo que no necesita retornarla (además desde `main()` no asignas el valor retornado por la función).

Por tanto podría quedar así:

```
def repite_pregunta (nombre):
  re_ingresar = True

  while re_ingresar:
    nombre.append(input())
    if nombre[-1] == '' :
      re_ingresar = False
```

Y llamarla así (como tú tenías):

```
a = []
repite_pregunta(a)
```

Sin embargo no se aconseja que las funciones modifiquen los parámetros. De hecho en general ni siquiera es posible hacerlo salvo que sea una lista (como este caso). Por consistencia y para que sea más fácil razonar sobre el programa, se aconseja que las funciones no cambien el valor de los parámetros, sino que retornen el resultado a través de un `return`.

Con este enfoque la función no necesitaría parámetros. Se llamaría así:

```
a = input_nombres()
```

y se implementaría así:

```
def input_nombres():
  re_ingresar = True
  nombres = []

  while re_ingresar:
    nombres.append(input())
    if nombres[-1] == '' :
      re_ingresar = False
  return nombres
```

(He aprovechado para cambiar el nombre de la lista a `nombres`, puesto que contendrá más de uno, y el de la función a `input_nombres()`, ya que es lo que hace. Elegir nombres de variables adecuados también es muy importante para ayudar a entender el código).